# How to change font of a menu item to regular from bold?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, fonts, menu, visual-c++

I want to change font of a menu item from bold to regular.
I looked few API's like
ModifyMenu
SetMenuItemInfo 
but looks like there is no direct API to change the font.

Any suggestions whats the easiest and best way to do that.

Comment: Be specific. What are you running? etc....

Answer (score 2):

At least as far as I know, this requires an [owner-drawn menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756947.aspx). As mentioned in the link, if you're willing to code strictly to Vista and newer, owner-drawn menus aren't necessary as often as they used to be, but:

1. Most developers still need to support XP
2. This case doesn't really fit what they're talking about anyway.